# Flask, REST, JQuery, JSONP trying to get data from one end to the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, rest, flask

What I've done so far.

Created a Flask app

```
from flask import Flask
import json
from os import path
app = Flask(__name__)

from functools import wraps
from flask import redirect, request, current_app

def jsonp(func):
    """Wraps JSONified output for JSONP requests."""
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        callback = request.args.get('callback', False)
        if callback:
            data = str(func(*args, **kwargs).data)
            content = str(callback) + '(' + data + ')'
            mimetype = 'application/javascript'
            return current_app.response_class(content, mimetype=mimetype)
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function


def getdatafromfile():
    my_dir = path.dirname(__file__)
    json_file_path = path.join(my_dir, 'items.json')
    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
        thedata = json.load(f)
    return str(thedata)


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
@jsonp
def test():
    thedata = getdatafromfile()
    return thedata

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The jsonp stuff I added after finding people facing issues similar to mine on here. If I run this directly in the browser

http://127.0.0.1:5000/test

I get the output I'm looking for

```
[{'country': ['United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'United Kingdom',
```

etc. same with curl -i

Then I created a simple HTML page with jquery and bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tour De France - Winners</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Tour De France Winners</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="container">
        <button id="button">ajax call</button>
        <div id="stuff"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            function onDataReceived (data){
            alert('test');
            };

            $("button").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: onDataReceived
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button I get the following URL generated in the console

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/test?callback=jQuery19008545286196749657_1455885069986&_=1455885069987
```

and a 500 error (in the console, silently).

If I paste that URL into my browser I get

```
builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'
```

with the traceback looking like this

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/antlockyer/PycharmProjects/tdfvis/tdfvis.py", line 15, in decorated_function
data = str(func(*args, **kwargs).data)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I'm very new to all this and would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Just a little bit more info. I deployed this to PyhtonAnywhere and it didn't work there either. Removing dataType: "jsonp" from the HTML page did however work.

Comment: you are sending a string, not json. dont cast to str

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for that.